# There was an error in query:

Tags: php

When i click on the delete button. The second page does not deletes the query instead says: There was an error in the query: No database selected Selected Rows deleted. I want to delete the selected queries.

which code should i include so that second page redirects to the first page?

query4.php

```
<html>
<title> Queries</title>
<body>
<h1> List of Queries</h1>
<form method=post action="delete4.php"> 
<?php
$ebits = ini_get('error_reporting');
error_reporting($ebits ^ E_NOTICE);// Turns off all the notices &warnings
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());//Connects to the DB
mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error()); //Selects one database
echo "<br />";
$query = "select * from queries ";
$result =  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); //sends a unique query to 

active database on the server
 $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<th><tr><td> 

</td><td>Name</td><td>Address</td><td>ContactNo</td><td>Query</td></tr></th>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{ 
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td><input type='checkbox' name='Query[]' value=\"".$row['queryId']."\"></td>"; 
echo " <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['address'] . "</td><td>" . $row
['contactNo'] . "</td><td>" . $row['query'] . "</td>";
echo"</tr>\n";
}  
?>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="Delete"> 
<br/>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

delete4.php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['Delete']))  
{
  foreach ($_POST['Query'] as $checkbox) 
  {
    echo "$checkbox";
    $conn= mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error());
    $del = mysql_query("DELETE * FROM queries WHERE queryId=$checkbox"); 
    $rs = mysql_query( $del) or die(mysql_error());
    if($rs)
    { 
      echo ("Records Deleted"); 
    }   
    else
    {
      echo ("No Way");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to reconnect to the database on every page.

Comment: What if i use this code:<?php 
if (isset($_POST['Delete']))  
{
foreach ($_POST['Query'] as $checkbox) 
{
echo "$checkbox";
$conn= mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$sql = mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error());
$del = mysql_query("DELETE * FROM queries WHERE queryId =" .$checkbox);  
$rs = mysql_query( $del) or die(mysql_error());
if($rs)
{ 
echo ("Records Deleted"); 
} 
else
{
echo ("No Way");
}
}
}
?>

Comment: @teana it's very hard to read in the comment - I'd say just try it out

Comment: What about this code? After running it says'Query was empty'<?php 
if (isset($_POST['Delete']))  
{
foreach ($_POST['Query'] as $checkbox) 
{
echo "$checkbox";
$conn= mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$sql = mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error());
$del = mysql_query("DELETE * FROM queries WHERE queryId =" .$checkbox);  
$rs = mysql_query( $del) or die(mysql_error());
if($rs)
{ 
echo ("Records Deleted"); 
} 
else
{
echo ("No Way");
}
}
}
?>

Comment: @teana: @Pekka means, that it is very hard to read your code in a comment, since there's no formatting. It's your question — why not edit the question and add it there, preferably nicely formatted?

Answer (score 0):

delete4.php should probably be:

```
<?php 
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error());
if (isset($_POST['Delete']))  
{
  foreach ($_POST['Query'] as $checkbox) 
  {
    echo "$checkbox";
    $del = mysql_query("DELETE * FROM queries WHERE queryId=$checkbox") 
    or die(mysql_error));

    if($del)
    { 
      echo ("Records Deleted"); 
    }   
    else
    {
      echo ("No Way");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Please note that there are plenty of improvements to be made.

You were connecting to the database within a `foreach` which is redundant, and a waste of resources - imagine if you had several thousand items to loop over - that would involve several thousand unnecessary calls being made.

You are also calling `mysql_query` twice, passing the result of the first query to the second, which will cause problems.

You can use a `header('Location:http://site.com/script.php');` to redirect to another page, but only if there is no output prior to the header call. In your script, you have html output, so this will not work without further modification.

Comment: If you mention improvements you also should mention database input sanitation.

Comment: @ Ross now it says: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM queries WHERE queryId=1' at line 1". And i want that delete4.php should redirect to query4.php. What to do in that case?